# split string containing special characters

Tags: bash

This is the string I have:

`COUNT(*) 154`

The part I need is `154` (the number after the space).

I tried `sed` and `cut` commands like for example: for sed:

```
's/COUNT(\*) //'
```

So only the number remains. But it doesn't work.

Comment: and you're sure that it's all on the same line? Typically there is a `\n` char (newline) separating a header from the value. Good luck.

Comment: @ikegami With `sed` they don't escaping by default - only when invoked with `-E` (basic vs. extended regexes).

Answer (score 2):

echo "COUNT(*) 154" | awk -F" " '{print $2}'

echo "COUNT(*) 154" | cut -d" " -f2

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "COUNT(*) 154"|awk '{print $NF}'
echo "COUNT(*) 154"|awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The sed solution:

```
sed -n 's/COUNT(\*) \([0-9]\+\)/\1/p' your-file
```

Answer (score 2):

bash's builtin `read` command can handle this:

```
$ s='COUNT(*) 154'
$ read a b <<< "$s"
$ echo $b
154
```

If there are multiple whitespace-separated words, read the string into an array:

```
$ s='COUNT (*) 154'
$ read -a words <<< "$s"
$ echo "${#words[@]}"
3
$ echo "${words[-1]}"
154
```

If, as @shelter suggests, your string actually contains a newline instead of a space:

```
$ s='COUNT(*)
154'
$ { read header; read value; } <<< "$s"
$ echo $value
154
```

Answer (score 2):

A Bash solution removing all non-digits:

```
str='COUNT(*) 154'

echo  "${str//[^0-9]/}"
```

The output is

```
154
```

Comment: Slightly more generic alternative: `echo "${str##* }"` - removes everything up to and including the last space - i.e., returns the last space-separated token.

Answer (score 1):

Rather crude, but if the `COUNT(*)` string doesn't change, and you want to use `cut` you can use:

```
echo "COUNT(*) 154" | cut -c10-
```

This will grab anything from the 10th character onward.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 <<<'COUNT(*) 154'
```

You're telling `cut` to return the 2nd space-delimited field.

Note that single-quoting the input string ensures its literal use, with no variable interpolation or shell expansions taking place.

**Update**: To address the original issue:

The OP's sed command, `'s/COUNT(\*) //'` actually works:

```
sed 's/COUNT(\*) //' <<< 'COUNT(*) 154'  # -> '154'
```

Note that `sed` uses *basic* regexes by default, so `()` must NOT be escaped - by contrast, `-E` expects *extended* regexes which DO require escaping of `()`:

```
sed -E 's/COUNT\(\*\) //' <<< 'COUNT(*) 154'  # -> '154'
```

That leaves us to wonder (as @shellter suggests) whether the input string is indeed just literal `COUNT(*) 154` and doesn't contain other chars. such as `\n`, `\r`, `t`.

An easy way to examine the actual characters is to use:

```
od -a <<< 'COUNT(*) 154'
```

This will a character-by-character representation of the input string (strictly speaking: byte-by-byte), with control characters represented symbolically; e.g.: `nl` for `\n`, `ht` for `\t`, `sp` for space.